# MySQL error code 1292 incorrect date value 1999 for column at row 1

Tags: mysql

This question has been addressed before many times, but the answers are about the **wrong format** of the date. The format of the date I have used is correct: `YYYY-MM-DD` according to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html).

**So what could be the possible cause of this error?**

I am using MySQL 5.5 if that matters.

**EDIT:-** 
The query I am trying to execute:-

```
insert into table2 (pk_id)
select pk_id from table1
where pk_date in  (2014-01-04, 2014-02-05, 2014-03-23, 2014-05-01, 2014-07-28) 
order by pk_id asc;
```

Comment: Show us the query and the actual values being used.

Comment: show the actual query you are trying.

Comment: `where pk_date in  ('2014-01-04', '2014-02-05', '2014-03-23', '2014-05-01', '2014-07-28') `

Comment: @JohnConde  I just edited my question. I left out other values of pk_date since that would needlessly lengthen the question.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Is there something wrong with the where clause?

Comment: yes date values are string and you need to enclose in single quote as I gave and also you need to remove the last comma in the IN list

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty post answer

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes just posted.

Comment: Remember the problem is with `IN` operator if you do `insert into table2 (pk_id) values (2014-02-05);` it will insert `0000-00-00 00:00:00` but it is `IN` operator what doesn't supports `2014-02-05`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is on the IN condition for dates, date is string and it needs to be quoted with single quote as

```
where pk_date in ('2014-01-04', '2014-02-05', '2014-03-23', '2014-05-01', '2014-07-28')
```